# Setting time interval in HTML5 server sent events

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-sent-events

I want to send regular updates from server to client. For that I used server-sent event. I'm pasting the codes below:

**Client side**

## Getting server updates

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!="undefined")
{
   var source=new EventSource("demo_see.php");
   source.onmessage=function(event)
   {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=event.data + "<br>";
   }
}
else
{
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support    server-sent events...";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Server side**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    $x=rand(0,1000);
    echo "data:{$x}\n\n";
    flush();
?>
```

The code works fine but it sends updates in every `3 seconds`. I want to send updates in milliseconds. I tried `sleep(1)` after `flush()` but it only increases the interval further by 1 sec. Does anyone have an Idea how I can accomplish this?

Also, can I send images using server-sent events?

Answer (score 18):

As discussed in the comments above running a PHP script in an infinite loop with a `sleep` or a `usleep` is incorrect for two reasons

- The browser will not see any event data (presumably it waits for the connection to close first) while that script is still running. I recall that early browser implementations of SSE allowed this but it is no longer the case.
- Even if it did work browser-side you would still be faced with the issue of having a PHP script that runs excessively long (until the PHP.ini time_out settings kick in). If this happens once or twice it is OK. If there are X thousand browsers that simultaneously seek the same SSE from your server it will bring down your server.

The right way to do things is to get your PHP script to respond with event stream data and then gracefully terminate as it would normally do. Provide a `retry` value - in milliseconds - if you want to control when the browser tries again.  Here is some sample code

```
function yourEventData(&$retry)
{
 //do your own stuff here and return your event data.
 //You might want to return a $retry value (milliseconds)
 //so the browser knows when to try again (not the default 3000 ms)
}

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');//optional

$data = yourEventData($retry);

echo "data:{$str}\n\nretry:{$retry}\n\n";
```

As an answer to the original question this is a *bit* late but nevertheless in the interests of completeness:

What you get when you poll the server in this way is just data. What you do with it afterwards is entirely up to you.  If you want to treat those data as an image and update an image displayed in your web page you would simply do

```
document.getElementById("imageID").src = "data:image/png;base64," + Your event stream data;
```

So much for the principles.  I have on occasion forgotten that `retry` has to been in milliseconds and ended up returning, for example, `retry:5\n\n` which, much to my surprise, still worked.  However, I would hesitate to use SSE to update a browser side image at 100ms intervals.  A more typical usage would be along the following lines

- User requests a job on the server. That job either gets *queued* behind other jobs or is likely to take quite a bit of time to execute (e.g. creating a PDF or an Excel spreadsheet and sending it back)
- Instead of making the user wait with no feedback - and risking a timeout - one can fire up an SSE which tells the browser the ETA for the job to finish and a `retry` value is setup so the browser knows when to look again for a result.
- The ETA is used to provide the user with some feedback
- At the end of the ETA the browser will look again (browsers do this automatically so you need do nothing)
- If for some reason the job is not completed by the server it should indicate that in the event stream it returns, e.g. `data{"code":-1}\n\n` so browser side code can deal with the situation gracefully.

There are other usage scenarios - updating stock quotes, news headlines etc. Updating images at 100ms intervals feels -a purely personal view - like a misuse of the technology.

---

It is now close to 5 years since I posted this answer and it still gets upvoted quite regularly.  For the benefit of anyone still using it as a reference - in many ways SSE is, in my view, a rather outdated technology.  With the advent of widespread support for WebSockets why bother doing SSE.  Quite apart from anything else the cost of setting up and tearing down an HTTPS connection from the browser for each browser side retry is very high. The WSS protocol is far more efficient.

A spot of reading if you want to implement websockets

1. [Client Side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)
2. [Server side via PHP with Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)
3. [With Nginx and NChan](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/Nchan/)

To my mind PHP is not a great language to handle websockets and Ratchet is far from easy to setup.  The Nginx/NChan route is far easier.

Comment: very informative answer, but I think while php is sleeping there should be nearly no load on the cpu from this script. I don't have any comparison between the load of a new connection if the browser comes every 100ms and php on sleep with php server timeout disabled

Comment: So this is the reason, why my php server returns 503 error when using an infinite loop, even if it breaks with data update. - It is no longer supported. :(

Comment: This is absolutely the answer. Sleeping should not be used, otherwise you will eventually hit your maximum execution time in PHP (like I did). Providing a single response with a retry value resolved this issue for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this behavior (message every 3 seconds) is explained [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/):

> The browser attempts to reconnect to the source roughly 3 seconds after each connection is closed

So one way to get message every 100 milliseconds is changing the reconnect time: (in the PHP)

```
echo "retry: 100\n\n";
```

This is not very elegant though, better approach would be endless loop in PHP that will sleep for 100 milliseconds on each iteration. There is good example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events), just changing the `sleep()` to `usleep()` to support milliseconds:

```
while (1) {
    $x=rand(0,1000);
    echo "data:{$x}\n\n";
    flush();
    usleep(100000); //1000000 = 1 seconds
}
```

Comment: I am slightly surprised that this answer has been upvoted twice. It suggests running the PHP script in an endless loop with a `usleep`. Imagine what happens if, say, X thousand browsers connect with your server demanding a server-sent-event? The right way for the PHP script is to quietly do its work and then terminate. Failing that the browser will simply not recognize the completion of the event and your server CPU will churn away... . With server sent events it is always for the browser to reconnect & the frequency is determined by the retry interval.

Comment: @DroidOS thanks, I wasn't aware of that. If you can write a better answer, it would be great. (not familiar enough with PHP to edit my answer)

Comment: actually, a fresh answer is not needed.  All you need to do is to get the PHP script to send back the event stream and terminate gracefully.  Naturally, the event stream can include a `retry:x\n\n` line where x is in milliseconds.  The browser deals with the rest.  It surprised me to find that Mozilla suggest such flawed PHP code for SSE. If you follow that example you will sooner or later dind that you max out your server.

Comment: @DroidOS thing is, I don't really know PHP. I gathered this one up thinking it's fine. If you can suggest an edit with the changes you talk about please do, and clarify in the summary you're doing it by my request so it won't get rejected. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the accepted answer may be **misleading**. Although it answers the question correctly (how to set up 1 second interval) it is not true that infinite loop is a bad approach in general.

SSE is used to get updates from the server when there actually are the updates opposed to Ajax polling that constantly checks for updates (even when there are none) in some time intervals. This can be accomplished with an infinite loop that keeps the server-side script running all the time, constantly checks for updates and echos them only if there are changes.

It is **not true** that:

> The browser will not see any event data while that script is still running.

You can run the script on the server and still sent the updates to the browser not ending the script execution like this:

```
while (true) {
  echo "data: test\n\n";
  flush();
  ob_flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

Doing it by sending retry parameter without infinite loop will end the script and then start the script again, end it, start again... This is similar to Ajax-polling checking for updates even if there are none and this is not how SSE is intended to work. Of course there are some situations where this approach is appropriate like it's listed in the accepted answer (for example waiting for server to create PDF and notify a client when it's done).

Using infinite loop technique will keep the script running on the server all time so you should be careful with a lot of users because you will have a script instance for each of them and it could lead to server overload. On the other hand, the same issue would happen even in some simple scenario where you suddenly get bunch of users on the website (without SSE) or if you would using Web Sockets instead of SSE. Everything has its own limitations.

Another thing to be careful about is what you put in the loop. For example, I wouldn't recommend putting database query in the loop that runs every second because then you're also putting a database at risk of overloading. I would suggest using some kind of cache (Redis or even simple text file) for this case.

Comment: I agree, in general, it is not a bad approach, but I'm not sure if infinite loop is good for PHP. Without proper logic, PHP can keep session lock and delay whole website or can keep executing even after disconnection. So I think we must be more careful for the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

SSE is an interesting technology, but one that comes with a choking side effect on implementations using **APACHE/PHP** backend.

When I first found out about SSE I got so excited that I replaced all Ajax polling code with SSE implementation. Only a few minutes of doing this I notice my CPU usage went up to **99/100** and the fear that my server was soon going to be brought down, forced me to revert the changes back to the friendly old Ajax polling. I love **PHP** and even though I knew SSE would work better on Node.is, I just wasn't ready to go that route yet!

After a period of critical thinking, I came up with an 
SSE **APACHE/PHP** implementation that could work without literally choking my server to death.

I'm going to share my SSE server side code with you, hopefully it helps someone overcome the challenges of implementing SSE with PHP.

```
<?php
/* This script fetches the lastest posts in news feed */
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

// prevent direct access
if ( ! defined("ABSPATH") ) die("");

/* push current user in session data into global space so 
we can release session lock */
$GLOBALS["exported_user_id"] = user_id();
$GLOBALS["exported_user_tid"] = user_tid();

/* now release session lock having exported session data 
in global space. if we don't do this, then no other scripts 
will run thus causing the website to lag even when 
opening in a new tab */
session_commit();

/* how long should this connection be maintained -
while we want to wait on the server long enoug for
update, holding the connection forever burn CPU 
resources, depending on the server resources you have 
available you can tweak this higher or lower. Typically, the 
higher the closer your implementation stays as an SSE 
otherwise it will be equivalent to Ajax polling. However, an 
higher time burns CPU resource especially when there's 
more users on your website */
$time_to_stay = strtotime("1 minute 30 seconds");

/* if no data is sent, we wait 2 seconds then abort 
connection. You can use this to test when a data you 
require for script operation is not passed along. Typically 
SSE reconnects after 3 seconds */
if ( ! isset( $_GET["id"] ) ){
exit;
}

/* if "HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID" is set, then this is a 
continue of temporily terminated script operation. This is 
important if your SSE is maintaining state you can use 
the header to get last event ID sent */ 
$last_postid = ( ( isset( 
$_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"] ) ) ? intval( 
$_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"] ) :
                                                     intval( $_GET["id"] ) );

/* keep the connection active until there's data to send to 
client */
while (true) {
/* You can assume this function perform some database
operations to get latest posts */
$data = fetch_newsfeed( $last_postid );

/* if data is not empty, we want to push back to the client 
then there must have been some new posts to push to 
client */
if ( ! empty( trim( $data ) ) ){
/* With SSE its my common practice to Json encode all 
data because I notice that not doing so, sometimes 
cause SSE to lose the data packet and only deliver a 
handful of the data on the client. This is bad since we are 
returning a structured HTML data and loosing some part 
of it will cause our HTML page to break when the data is 
inserted in our page */
$data = json_encode(array("result" => $data));

 echo "id: $last_postid \n"; // this is the lastEventID 
 echo "data: $data\n\n"; // our data
 /* flush to avoid waiting for script to terminate - make 
 sure its in the same order */
 @ob_flush(); flush(); 
}

// the amount of time that has been spent on this script
$time_stayed = intval(floor($time_to_stay) - time());
/* if we have stayed more than time to stay, then abort 
this connection to free up CPU resource */
if ( $time_stayed <= 0 ) { exit; }

/* we simply wait 5 seconds and continue again from 
start . We don't want to keep pounding our DB since we 
are in a tight loop so we sleep a few seconds and start 
from top*/
 sleep(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SSE on Nginx driven PHP websites seems to have some finer nuances. Firstly, I had to give this setting in the Location section of the Nginx configuration

```
 fastcgi_buffering off;
```

Someone recommended that I change the fastcgi_read_timeout to a longer period but it did not really help... or maybe I did not dive deep enough

```
  fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

Both those settings are to be given in the Nginx configuration's location section.

The standard endless loop that many are recommending inside the SSE code tends to hang Nginx (or possibly PHP7.4fpm ) and that is serious; as it brings down the entire server. Though people have suggested set_time_out(0) in PHP to change the default time out (which I believe is 30 seconds) I am not very sure it is a good strategy

If you remove the endless loop entirely, the SSE system seems to work like polling: The Javascript code for EventSource keeps calling back the SSE PHP module. Which made it a bit more simpler than Ajax polling (as we don't have to write any extra code for Javascript to do that polling) but nevertheless, it is still going to keep retrying and hence is very similar to Ajax polling. And each retry is a complete reload of the PHP SSE code, so it is slower than what I finally did.

This is what worked for me. It is a hybrid solution, where there is a loop alright, but not an endless one. Once that loop is finished, the SSE PHP code terminates. That gets registered in the browser as a failure (You can see that in the inspector console) and the browser then calls the SSE code once again on the server. It is like polling, but at longer intervals.

In between one load of the SSE and the next reload, the SSE keeps working in the loop, during which additional data can be pushed into the browser. So you do have enough speed, without the headache of the entire server hanging.

```
<?php
$success = set_time_limit( 0 );
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');

ob_end_clean();

   
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');

//how fast do you want the browser to reload this SSE
//after the while loop fails:
echo "retry: 200\n\n"; 
//If any dynamic data comes into your application 
//in this 'retry' time period, and disappears, 
//then SSE will NOT be able to push that data
//If it is too short, there may be insufficient 
//time to finish some work within the execution
//of one loop of the SSE while loop below  

$emptyCount = 0;
$execCount = 0;
$countLimit = 60; //Experiment with this, which works for you 
$emptyLimit = 5;
$prev = "";

while($execCount < $countLimit){

   $execCount++;
   if( connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL or connection_aborted() ) break;


   if(file_exists($file_path)) {

     //The file is to be deleted 
     //so that it does not return back again
     //There can be better method than one suggested here
     //But not getting into it, as this is only about SSE overall
     $s= file_get_contents("https://.....?f=$file_path");
      if($s == "")
         { 
          $emptyCount++;
          $prev = "";
         } 
       else {
         if($s != $prev){
            $prev = $s;
            echo $s; //This is formatted as data:...\n\n 
                     //as needed by SSE
         }
      }

      //If it is continually empty then break out of the loop. Why hang around?
      if($emptyCount >$emptyLimit) {
          $emptyCount=0;  
          $prev = "";         
          break;
      } 

     } else $prev = ""; 

     @ob_flush();
     @flush();
     sleep(1);
   
    
  }
```