# What determines how often a sever-sent-event is triggered

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I am new to server-sent-events and copied the tutorial example from the w3 site.

The html page:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
        var source = new EventSource("sse.php");
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data + "<br>";
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The php script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

This works and the page gets updated every 5 seconds.

My question is: Why 5 seconds?  Is this a default setting for SSEs or is it something to do with the php date functionality or some php.ini setting?

*EDIT*

I change the php to this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

while(true)
{
    $time = date('r');
    echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

and I get nothing, as if it is waiting for the php script to finish running (which it never will).

*EDIT 2*

PHP now changed to this (includes proper flush as suggested):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

while(true)
{
    $time = date('r');
    echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";

    while (ob_get_level() > 0)
        ob_end_flush();
    flush();

    if (connection_aborted())
        break;

    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Still doing nothing.

Comment: how is that running more than once? all simple SSE examples I've ever seen have a loop in the server side code to send events periodically - your code sends one and is done

Comment: That's what I don't understand also.

Comment: because `EventSource` will attempt to reconnect for you - it's in the spec

Comment: So what sets the reconnect at 5 seconds?  Or how do I stop it re-connecting?

Comment: according to google searches, the reconnect time is "about 3 seconds" - but you can control that from the server in a message which sets the reconnect time ... however, that's NOT how you want to use SSE's - as a single event followed by closing and reopening the connection some time later - you may as well be polling from the client

Comment: OK, I have edited question with inclusion of loop but now it does nothing.

Comment: see the simple example at https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/server-sent-events/sse.php#L22 - perhaps you need a proper flush - which your original code wouldn't need, since it was closing the connection

Comment: Proper flush added - still doing nothing.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315137/setting-time-interval-in-html5-server-sent-events help?

Comment: Nico, it seems that SSEs are not meant for the thing I am trying.  It can work with a restart, but that defeats the object.  Thanks for finding that related question.