# Implement Server side events with Laravel/php-fpm/nginx

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to implement server side events with Laravel.
My implementation of SSE endpoint:

```php
public function stream()
{
    session_write_close(); 
    session_commit();
    return response()->stream(function() {
        set_time_limit(300);
        $lastMessage = Message::latest('id')->first(); 
        $now = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
        $lastMessage = is_null($lastMessage) ? $now : Carbon::parse($lastMessage->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
        session_write_close(); 
        session_commit();
        ob_start();
        for ($i=0;$i<300;$i++) {
            if (connection_aborted() || connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL) {
                break;
            }
            $storedMessages = \Cache::rememberForever('stored_messages', function () use ($lastMessage) {
                return Message::where('created_at', '>', $lastMessage)->get();
            });
            if (!$storedMessages->isEmpty()) {
                \Cache::forget('stored_messages');
                $lastMessage = Carbon::parse($storedMessages->last()->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
                echo "event: message\n", "data: " . json_encode($storedMessages), "\n\n";
            }
            echo "\n\n";
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(1);
        }
        ob_end_flush();
    }, 200, [
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream',
        'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
        'X-Accel-Buffering' => 'no',
    ]);
}
```

Front side:

```js
this.evtSource = new EventSource('/api/stream');
this.evtSource.addEventListener('message', event => {
    JSON.parse(event.data).forEach(message => {
        this.receivedMessages.push(message);
    });
}, false);
// Reconnection function follows for when the loop ends
```

This works as long as less than 10 browsers/tabs are viewing the page that opens the connection to the stream endpoint. **When 11th tab is opened, whole website hangs.** (I'm using http2, so I think this not a connection limit)
I checked what is causing the behavior, and I found out that "max_children" of php-fpm was causing this. But I think this number cannot be increased to a big number.

I googled SSE examples of php, but many of them had same problem.
I also found this question: [Setting time interval in HTML5 server sent events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315137/setting-time-interval-in-html5-server-sent-events/46138860)
The most upvoted answer says we should remove the infinite loop and "keep retrying the endpoint" until update is detected, but I think this is just a "polling". Not realtime update and server load not reduced.

I just want to push notifications to users, so I thought introducing websocket (along with websocket servers etc...) is too much for this purpose. So my question is: is it possible to use Server Side Events with Laravel/php-fpm/nginx? If possible, how?

Edit:
My whole implementation for your reference.
https://github.com/lechatthecat/laravel-soketi-broadcast-example-by-websocket/tree/http2_server_side_events

Comment: It really comes down to memory. The setting `max_children` is generally “available memory / amount of memory your application needs”. On a single box you might lose more available memory because of database, Redis, etc. Increasing your available memory physically is an option, decreasing your process memory is another, as well as trying to force GC.

Comment: You can feel free and increase the amount of max_children to more suitable for your needs. As an example, you can use this article: https://serverfault.com/questions/939436/understand-correctly-pm-max-children-tuning
Personally, I would prefer using on of the existing solutions like echo (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting), as it has much better support.

Comment: Otherwise, another option is to use Mercure which is what [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html) recommends and shouldn’t be too hard to bring to Laravel. You basically spin up a dedicated server for connection pooling (the Hub), clients connect to _it_ using something similar to SSE, and the server pushes to it, too.

Comment: Thank you ChrisHaas and SergeiShitikov. I think increasing number of max_children doesn't solve the problem because, even if it's increased to 1000, when 1001th tab is opened, I think the whole website hangs in the same way. Our website has very high traffic. My impression is, if we use SSE, we must use frameworks that provide non blocking IO like Node.js.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, Mercure sounds interesting. Thank you for your suggestion.